Why is my MOSFET gate driver resistor burning out?
I'm trying to build a ~20W LED light recently, and below is the schematic and PCB layout of the driving part.


In this design, I used a PD deception chip CH224K to request a 20V voltage from the USB interface, and then used PT4115 (datasheet) as the LED driver chip.
In previous tests, I found that the PT4115 heats up severely, so I didn't directly use it to drive the LED light. Instead, I added an independent gate driver (datasheet) and MOSFET. However, after powering on, the gate resistor (R9) burns out within a few seconds (becomes few kΩ and causes severe heating on the MOSFET, but the light still works).
Theoretically, the current passing through this driving resistor should be only about 56.9nC×~250kHz×2  = ~28mA(MOSFET Qg × theoretical switching frequency of PT4115 in this circuit × charging and discharging), which should not cause it to burn out.
I have tried replacing this resistor, but because it burns out so quickly, I cannot figure out what happens before it burns out.
In addition, here's an explanation for some "strange designs" in the schematic:

6 500mΩ resistors: These are current sensing resistors for the PT4115. It attempts to maintain a voltage drop of 100mV across these resistors. I installed 6 of them because I didn't have other suitable resistors on hand.
MOSFET: This is a high-power MOSFET with an R(DSon) of only 2mΩ, in a DFN5 5x6 package. Its specifications far exceed the requirements of this project. I used it simply because I had extras from a DIY BLDC driver project, and I didn't want to waste such a good MOSFET.
R8: The output of the PT4115 is essentially an open-drain output, so I used this resistor to pull up the signal. I've measured the waveform here with an oscilloscope, and the pull-up speed is entirely sufficient.


20V is the absolute maximum Vgs for that MOSFET, not a working value. Is it breaking down and taking a huge gate current?

@Finbarr  The datasheet of the MOSFET said it has ±100 nA Gate-Source Leakage Current when VGS=±20V and VDS=0V. Also, despite the heating issue casused by charging too slow, this MOSFET is still working, so I don't think this is the real reason

...and the UCC27517 has a maximum supply voltage of 18V.

I actually used the UCC27517DBVR-JSM as a replacement chip instead of the UCC27517DBVR. However, since its datasheet is in Chinese, I provided the link of the latter in the post. The  former can withstand a maximum voltage of 25V. I apologize for not noticing this earlier.

None of the graphs in the MOSFET datasheet show Vgs of more than 10V, that should tell you something.

The device operates using PWM to dim the LED.  If you have a scope, make sure that the drain is not voltage is not spiking.  It may be pulling the 20V supply up through D2.
